# meaning of "critical errands"

Tags: meaning

[From cnet](https://www.cnet.com/health/16-coronavirus-tips-how-to-help-keep-yourself-healthy-when-going-out-in-public/)

> As coronavirus lockdown restrictions ease and cities reopen around the world, the way you'll go to restaurants, malls and hair salons will change, so it's a good idea to think about how you'll keep yourself and your loved ones healthy during a prolonged period.
>
> If you're not part of a vulnerable group, becoming a hermit isn't necessarily the solution, either. It's beneficial to periodically leave the house to maintain your health and sanity and **run critical errands**, but there are measures you can take when coming within spitting distance of people outside the household.

I understand the meanings of the words "critical" and "errands" separately.

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/errand?q=errands)

> a short trip you make to do something, such as buying or delivering things in the neighborhood
>
> I’ve got to run a few errands (= do errands) and then stop by my mother’s.

[From The American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=critical)

> Extremely important or essential: a critical element of the plan; a second income that is critical to the family's well-being. See Synonyms at indispensable.

Does "critical errands" refer to "extremely important errands"?

Comment: Yes, extremely important errands. For example, going to the grocery store to get food. That's critically important because you must eat.